# AdBlock is not working in iOS when provide data dynamically?

Tags: ios, swift

I am downloading data and providing to NSItemProvider but it seems it is not reading data from NSUserDefaults. When i provide list of small number of rules the error didn't came, but when i add more rules in my blocker list it gives error, It means there is limit of data to provide on App Group.
*HERE SOME CODE*

```
 let data=NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("data")?.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)//NSData(contentsOfURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("blockerList", withExtension: "json")!)let attachment = NSItemProvider(item: data, typeIdentifier: kUTTypeJSON as String)let item = NSExtensionItem()
item.attachments = [attachment]context.completeRequestReturningItems([item], completionHandler: nil);
```

Answer (score 0):

The data will be provided by creating App Group.
you can use var defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.xxxxx")!
it will work after researching i found the solution.